# Composition of a piecewise function with itself

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Let $f(x)=x+2,\hspace{1cm}-4\leq x\leq 0 $
$\hspace{1.5cm}=2-x^2,\hspace{1cm}0< x\leq 4$
then find $f(f(x)),$ domain of $f(f(x))$.

---

The domain of $f(f(x))$ is intersection of $-4\leq f(x)\leq 4$ and $-4\leq x\leq 4$.I drew the graph of $f(x)$ and found $-4\leq f(x)\leq 4$ implies $-4\leq x\leq \sqrt6$.So the resultant intersection is $-4\leq x\leq \sqrt6$.
My domain is correct as it is given in the books answer.
I found 
$f(f(x))=x+4,\hspace{2.5cm}-4\leq x\leq-2$
$\hspace{1.5cm}=-x^2-4x-2,\hspace{1cm}-2< x\leq0$
$\hspace{1.5cm}=-x^4+4x^2-2,\hspace{1cm}0< x\leq\sqrt2$
$\hspace{1.5cm}=4-x^2,\hspace{2cm}\sqrt2< x\leq\sqrt6$
I am not sure whether my answer is correct or not.As the answer in the book is not given.
Can you please comment on whether this is right or not.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your computation is okay. Seems that your $f$ is continuous , and even  $f\circ f$ is also continuous.